# Magento 2 Programmatically adding a ViewModel to a Block when Creating it

Tags: magento2, controllers

I have hit a problem when trying to create a block in a controller in so much as I need the block created in the controller to also create a ViewModel type object.

What I am trying to achieve but I wish to do this via code in the controller rather than using the layout file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <Block name="expert.reviews.tab" class="Bub\AdvancedReview\Block\ExpertReview\ExpertReviews" template="Bub\AdvancedReview::expert_reviews.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="advanced-review-helper" xsi:type="object">Bub\AdvancedReview\Helper\BlockHelper</argument>
                </arguments>
            </Block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My code in the controller is as follows:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Bub\AdvancedReview\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout;
use Magento\Review\Controller\Product as ProductController;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

class ExpListAjax extends ProductController implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Show list of product's reviews
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface|Layout
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
        $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();

        /** @var \Bub\AdvancedReview\Block\ExpertReview\ExpertReviews $block */
        $block = $layout->createBlock(\Bub\AdvancedReview\Block\ExpertReview\ExpertReviews::class,null,['advanced-review-helper' => 'Bub\AdvancedReview\Helper\BlockHelper']);
        $block->setTemplate('Bub_AdvancedReview::expert_reviews.phtml');
        $layout->createBlock()->setData();


        return $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

Does anybody know if this can be done?

Thankyou in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You will have to inject an instance of the `Bub\AdvancedReview\Helper\BlockHelper` via the contsructor (di) and pass it as an object instead of a string:

```
$block = $layout->createBlock(
    '\Bub\AdvancedReview\Block\ExpertReview\ExpertReviews',
    'bubs_name_for_the_block',
    [
        'data' => [
            'advanced-review-helper' => $this->bubsHelper
        ]
    ]
);
```